# How can I prevent VS Code from opening the 'Code - OSS Dev' folder after installing an extension and restarting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Seivan.swipe-to-navigate) which required a restart of VS Code. When it did restart it was a completely fresh install of VS Code. I did a bit of digging and found that my `Code` folder (`/Library/Application Support/Code`) with all of my preferences/configuration/settings etc wasn't being used anymore after the restart and VS Code was opening from a "Code - OSS Dev" (`/Library/Application Support/Code - OSS Dev`) folder instead. How do I stop using this OSS Dev version and go back to using the normal Code version?

**Action**:
Installed [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Seivan.swipe-to-navigate)

**Expected Behaviour**:
Extension is installed and I continue using VS Code

**Actual Behaviour**:
VS Code boots from a different `Code` folder and I am stuck using a clean install of VS Code

Answer (score 0):

If you learn about the extension carefully, you will see that it relies on a dangerous extension that "patched" VS Code official bits, and tries to do its own hacks, and that breaks VS Code on the route,

https://github.com/iocave/monkey-patch/issues/66

How to resolve it? Stop using any of such extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's best that you delete Visual Studio Code.app along with .vscode-oss/ and /Library/Application Support/Code - OSS Dev folders.
And reinstall.
Temporary solution that worked for me is -

1. Go to Applications/Visual Studio
   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js
2. Replace the file content with 'bootstrap-amd.js.monkey-patch' content.
   This will prevent loading of monkey-patch modules

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run the following command from the command palette: > Disable Monkey Patch